# Why it has not animation while removing div?

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

In my project, I use vue.js 2.9.
I have defined animations for moving in and removing ( transition and translated):

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
&.move-enter-active, &.move-leave-active
  transition: all 0.2s linear
&.move-enter, &.move-leave
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0)
```

My template div is :

```
<template>
  <transition name="move">
    <div v-show="showFlag" class="food" ref="food">
      <div class="food-content"></div>
    </div>
  </transition>
<template>
```

I have tried:

```
&.move-enter, &.move-leave-to
  transform: translated3d(100%, 0, 0)
```

and

```
&.move-enter, &.move-leave-active
  transform: translated3d(100%, 0, 0)
```

There are Ok. "&.move-leave-to" can be easy understand.

but "&.move-leave-active" makes me confuse.

who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `v-leave-to` class instead of `v-leave` to set the *final* state for the leave transition.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showFlag: true
  }
})
```

```css
.food {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.food.move-enter-active, .food.move-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.food.move-enter, .food.move-leave-to {
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition name="move">
    <div v-show="showFlag" class="food" ref="food">
      <div class="food-content">Food content</div>
    </div>
  </transition>
  <p><button @click="showFlag = !showFlag">Toggle</button></p>
</div>
```

The reason `v-leave` wasn't working is due to...

> Starting state for leave. Added immediately when a leaving transition is triggered, **removed after one frame**.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes

Comment: I have tested .food.move-leave-active instead of .food.move-leave-to, It can also run successfully, I don't know why

Comment: The _active_ classes are always on during the transition. The documentation suggests those are the classes you should use to set the duration, delay and easing (which is what you are doing already). The `-to` classes define the desired end state so I think you should use them